# Why virtualenv doesn't have same python version

Tags: python, virtualenv, macports

I use macports to keep my software up to date, In macports my python version is `2.7.5`, I create my virtualenv and then check the `python --version` of the newly created virtual environment and the python version is `2.6.1`. Based on my understanding virtualenv should have the same python version since I created it from 2.7.5.

when I do which python I get the correction location which is the location that macports installs its software packages.

```
~/code]$python --version
Python 2.7.5
~/code]$which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

What would be the reason virtualenv to have different python --version.

Comment: Did you install ``virtualenv`` with the macports Python, or the system one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtualenv was installed against the system Python and not the macports version. To use the the macports version of Python, pass it in as a parameter:

```
virtualenv --python=/opt/local/bin/python
```

If you want to make this permanent, set the `VIRTUALENV_PYTHON` variable in your shell and point it to the Python from macports:

```
$ export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/opt/local/bin/python
$ virtualenv new_venv
```

You could also uninstall the existing virtualenv library and install the one from macports:

```
port select --list virtualenv
port select --set virtualenv virtualenv27
which virtualenv
```

Comment: I actually tried `export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/opt/local/bin/python` prior to posting the question but it didn't work.